# Solution about a Michael Aschbacher exercise [edit]

Tags: group-theory

I really need the solution of the exercise 11.4 (page 174) in
M. Aschbacher, *Finite group theory*. Here is the text of the exercise.

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $p$ a prime, $\Omega$ a $G$-invariant collection of $p$-subgroups of $G$, $P$ a $p$-subgroup of $G$, and $\Delta\subseteq\{P\cap A:A\in\Omega\}$. Let's assume that for all $X,Y\in\Delta$ and for all $y\in Y$ $X^y\in\Delta$. Prove that either
>
> a) $\Delta=\{P\cap A:A\in\Omega\}$
>
> b) There exists $X\in(P\cap\Omega)\setminus\Delta$ such that for all $X\in\Delta$ and for all $s\in S$ $X^s\in\Delta$..

I tried supposing $\Delta\neq P\cap\Omega$ and splitting the two cases in which $P\in\Omega$ and $P\notin\Omega$. I feel that this exercise is not so difficult but I can't get the answer..

Can anyone help me? Thank you all :)

Comment: @Xoque55: You haven't been very active in group theory questions here. Are you sure you would be able to tell the difference between a serious attempt and a fake one?

Comment: I tried supposing $\Delta\neq P\cap\Omega$ and splitting the two cases in which $P\in\Omega$ and $P\notin\Omega$. I feel that this exercise is not so difficult but I can't get the answer..

Comment: Federico: Please **edit** that explanation of your own thoughts to be a part of the question body. That pre-empts close votes. Particularly from people who have never heard of a $p$-group :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen No, I'm not active in group theory so I am not nearly as qualified as other users to discern between serious and fake attempts. *However*, I am capable of knowing whether an OP has made any attempt vs. no attempt. And prompting an OP to get the hang of this site is something I am more capable of.

Comment: So $P$ is a subgroup and $\Omega$ is a set of subgroups. How do you define $P \cap \Omega$? Is it $\{ P \cap Q \mid Q \in \Omega \}$? Is $\Delta$ a subgroup or a set of subgroups?

Comment: Yes, $P\cap \Omega$ is defined as you think :) so $\Delta$ is a set of subgroups

Comment: With technical questions like this, you need to avoid typos. I think you mean "there exists $X \in (P \cap \Omega) \setminus \Delta$ with ..."

Comment: Sorry, you're true :( edited

Comment: Is there anybody that could help me? :)